# How to print two fields from a text file?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a log file in my machine having the below mentioned contents.

```
2020-06-18 00:01:31|INFO|0||pro_upl_postpaid_trap|ComUpload|CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp[95]|rename remote file success,source filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/ovou20200617_999_400280.unl.temp,destination filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/**ovou20200617_999_400280.unl**
2020-06-18 00:01:32|INFO|0||pro_upl_postpaid_trap|ComUpload|CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp[95]|rename remote file success,source filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/ocom20200617_512_400106.unl.temp,destination filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/ocom20200617_512_400106.unl
2020-06-18 00:01:32|INFO|0||pro_upl_postpaid_trap|ComUpload|CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp[95]|rename remote file success,source filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/ocom20200617_515_400184.unl.temp,destination filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/ocom20200617_515_400184.unl
2020-06-18 00:01:33|INFO|0||pro_upl_postpaid_trap|ComUpload|CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp[95]|rename remote file success,source filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/odata20200617_517_400092.unl.temp,destination filename=/file_src/localusers/data/TRAP_CBS/recv/odata20200617_517_400092.unl
```

I wanted to print 3 fields out of this log file like the below:

```
2020-06-18 00:01:31|**ovou20200617_999_400280.unl**
```

I was able to print the last field but couldn't able to print both date/time (2020-06-18 00:01:31) and the file name (ovou20200617_999_400280.unl) together..!!!

```
cat pro_upl_*_trap_$YestodayDate*|grep 'CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp' |awk -F "/" '{print $19}'
```

Any hints/help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're grep-ing for `CUploadProcessRemoteFile.cpp` when it's present in every line but assuming you do have a reason for it, you never need `grep` when you're using `awk`, nor do you need `cat` to open the input file for `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[|/]' -v OFS='|' '/CUploadProcessRemoteFile\.cpp/{print $1, $NF}' file
2020-06-18 00:01:31|**ovou20200617_999_400280.unl**
2020-06-18 00:01:32|ocom20200617_512_400106.unl
2020-06-18 00:01:32|ocom20200617_515_400184.unl
2020-06-18 00:01:33|odata20200617_517_400092.unl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk with multiple delimiters:

```
awk -F'[|/]' '{print $1, $NF}'
```

Comment: That's the same answer I posted an hour ago but without the extra functionality the OP needs.